# Thread Synchronization in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 5 long running process and I need to execute only one Task at a time; I am planning to put them on 5 threads and my only condition is only one thread needs to be exeucuted...

Can you give any example for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me, you want to run 5 threads but only one can execute?  Please clarify your question?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If you don't want to run them all at the same time, why are you using different threads?

Comment: Use a threadpool, or backgroundworkers in C#

Answer (score 10):

When you need to execute "one at a time" then **do not** use more than 1 Thread...

Simply execute them in order on 1 Thread.

Comment: yeah, a foreach(var task in logRunningTasks) task.Run() should do the trick

Comment: 9 votes before the 5 minute edit window has elapsed. Maybe I should reconsider the things I've said on Meta about this not being a problem... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly that you want to execute all 5 threads one after the other. Like: thread 2 shall only start once thread 1 has finished?

Then you can have:

```
Thread T1 = ...
Thread T2 = ...
Thread T3 = ...
..
Thread T5 = ...

T1.Start();
T1.Join();

T2.Start();
T2.Join();

...

T5.Start();
T5.Join();
```

But in this case I would advice you to only use 1 thread, that makes things easier.